# How to copy static file to the output dir in IntelliJ Idea IDE for the java build configuration?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, artifact

I am creating the client-server application in java. I have created three modules:

1. Client
2. NetworkModels - serializable models
3. Server

Client should ask the server to parse the xml file, xml file should be stored on the server. I have setup two build configurations as on the screen, one for the client and one for the server:

[image: Build configurations]

I have added file "Employees.xml" like on the next screen, I was expected that file will copied to output directory on the build

[image: Adding Employees.xml]

But actually when run build, the file not copied to the ouput, all I have is jar:
[image: Only jar]

I want this to be able to place a xml file in the same directory as server.jar and than run the server.jar, see this code, which tries to read the file from the same location where executing jat is placed:

```
private File getEmployeesXmlFile() throws Exception {
    var classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    var pathToExecutedJar = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
    var tempFile = new File(pathToExecutedJar);
    var currentDirectory = tempFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
    var pathToEmployeesXml = currentDirectory + "/employees.xml";
    var employeesXmlFile = new File(pathToEmployeesXml);
    if (employeesXmlFile == null) {
        throw new Exception("Employees xml file not found at " + currentDirectory);
    }

    return employeesXmlFile;
}
```

The xml file is undo server module on `resources/employees.xml` path, I have added this wildcards to resource patterns, hoping that file will be copied to the server output, but it not helps:

[image: Adding resource patterns]

What I want is to edit file in IDE and copy it to the output on build. Currently I have placed 'employees.xml' manually in the out dir.

Answer (score 0):

> I want this to be able to place a xml file in the same directory as server.jar

You say you want to place it near the jar but you include it into a jar artifact - so it is packed inside the jar.

For IDE to copy the resource file to output dir: the file must be placed in the `resources` directory. Then see the [module's output directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/specifying-compilation-settings.html#specify_compilation_output_folders) where IDE places this file on build.

What you can do to place it near the jar is to configure an Ant task in **Post-processing** tab in the artifact configuration to be run after IDE builds the artifact.